# How do you use std::distance to find the array index of a pointer to an std::array element?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

Let's say I have a std::array of some object and create a pointer to one of the objects.

```
std::array<Object, 100> my_array;

Object* ptr_object = &my_array[50];
```

So assuming I don't know the index referred to by ptr_object, how would I go about and back-track to find this index in C++11?

I've come across some readings that suggest std::distance might help, however, my attempt of

```
std::distance(my_array, ptr_object);
```

throws an error stating that "no matching overloaded function found".

Comment: Post some compilable code that illustrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I believe what I posted is a concise and clear question.

Comment: You want the distance from the start of the array to `ptr_object`  , so you have to write something that specifies the start of the array (not the whole array as you have done)

Comment: I believe not - for example, you don't show what you are trying to do with `std::distance(my_array, ptr_object);` That function returns a value.

Comment: @NeilButterworth that's not relevant to the question

Comment: Why do you want to use `std::distance` instead of plain pointer arithmetic? Is this a requirement?

Comment: @AnT I don't have a good reason in all honesty. I just typically try to use language features when possible.

Comment: If you want to use `std::distance()`, then you'll need to pass `std::begin(my_array)` as its first argument, not `my_array` itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to get the index is to use pointer arithmetic.  Simply subtract a pointer to the desired element from a pointer to the first element, eg:

```
size_t index = (ptr_object - my_array.data()/*&my_array[0]*/);
```

`std::distance()` takes iterators as input, and raw pointers can be used as iterators.  So, you can use a pointer to the first element as the starting iterator, and a pointer to the desired element as the ending iterator, eg:

```
size_t index = std::distance(my_array.data()/*&my_array[0]*/, ptr_object);
```

Note how this differs from your code, where you try to pass the `std::array` itself to `std::distance()`.  That does not work.

Both of the above have constant complexity, since they are simple arithmetic operations (`std::distance()` is optimized for random-access iterators, like raw pointers and `std::array` iterators).

Alternatively, you can use actual iterators instead, but that requires iterating through the array to get an iterator to the desired element without knowing its index beforehand, eg:

```
auto iter = std::find_if(std::begin(my_array), std::end(my_array), [=](Object &o) { return (&o == ptr_object); });
size_t index = std::distance(my_array.begin(), iter);
```

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer `my_array.data()` over `my_array.begin()`?

Comment: Another option is `&my_array[0]`

Comment: @M.M yes, provided `N > 0`. though `begin()` and `data()` are a little cleaner than `&[0]`, and more STL-ish.

Comment: @PaulRooney: `data()` is a **pointer** to the 1st element.  `begin()` is an **iterator** to the 1st element. Pointers can always be used as iterators, but iterators are not always pointers.

Comment: yes I understand that distinction. I was just curious about if `begin` could be the wrong thing to use in any situations.

Comment: @PaulRooney well, it would be wrong to use `begin()` in the first 2 situations I presented, since `begin()` returns an iterator that is not guaranteed to be a pointer, but they require 2 pointers to work correctly, not a pointer and an iterator. `begin()` is appropriate to use in the 3rd situation I presented, which uses only iterators.

Comment: yeah in the first one absolutely, but for the second. I'd have though that its equivalent. I guess they aren't unless you assume that iterators are pointers. Anyway, I'm not trying to be argumentative, I'm only trying to get it straight in my head :)

Comment: Note that if `std::find` or `std::find_if` does not find the requested value, `std::distance` will return the distance to `std::end(my_array)` which could lead to subtle bugs if that case is not handled.

Comment: @jb true, but in the case provided, the requested object is known to be in the array, so `find(_if)` will not return the `end` iterator

Answer (score 5):

I would advise against gratuitous use of `std::distance`, unless it is a requirement in your case.

`std::distance` is an interface-unifying function, whose purpose is to allow one to calculate distances between various kinds of iterators: random-access, bidirectional, forward etc. This function is intended to conceal the inefficiency of directly calculating the distance for non-random-access iterators, in situations where you really know what you are doing and really want to accept that inefficiency. It is intended to stand out in your code (like a cast), signalling the fact that in general case the code might be inefficient, but you are willing to accept that at least for now, like in temporary "sketch" code. (The same applies to `std::advance`).

If you do not intend to "hide" the inefficiency, i.e. you intend your code to work with random-access iterators only, don't use `std::distance`. Just subtract the iterators

```
std::ptrdiff_t i = ptr_object - my_array.data();
```